# Good practises for JSON answer

Tags: node.js, json

I have a test task about creating NodeJS service for solving quadratic equations in real numbers. The service has to send JSON with answers. There are could be three situations: two answers, one answer, no answers (like then D < 0) + situations when a,b,c were invalid. So for three common situations idea is to send JSONs like that:

Two answers:

```
 {
    "answers":[ "answer1", "answer2" ]
 }
```

One answer:

```
{
"answers":[ "answer"]
}
```

No answers:

```
{
"answers":[]
}
```

Does it look nice? If it doesn't can you recommend me some good practices?

Comment: You could also just return the array directly. But ultimately this is subjective IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this JSON structure is valid and appropriate for what you are trying to achieve.